# Creating New Page with WP_INSERT_POST Issue

Tags: wp-insert-post

I am trying to create a new page using the **wp_insert_post()** function as follows:

```
$page = array('post_type'   => 'page'
             ,'post_title'  => 'The Resolution AR'
             ,'post_status' => 'publish'
             ,'post_author' => 1
             ,'post_slug'   => 'the-resolution-ar-2019'
);

$page_id = wp_insert_post($page);
```

A page does get created. Except, it gets created with the wrong post_slug.

When I look in WP_POSTS I see the post_slug as: **the-resolution-ar**

For some reason the function does not like the **-2019** portion of the slug I am providing and automatically removes it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `post_name` instead of `post_slug` (post_slug isn't valid in `wp_insert_post`). Just make sure you don't accidentally create pages with duplicate slugs.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.I am checking to make sure the page doesn't already exist using `$page_check = get_page_by_title($page_title);` and `if ( !isset($page_check->ID) && !the_slug_exists($page_slug) )`. Seems to be working great now!